# The schemes of physical constants; is newtonian mechanics the exception?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics, history, physical-constants

Every subcategory of physics starts with a physical constant that is always the same:

$k_B:$ Thermodynamics/ Statistical Mechanics

$c:$ Special Relativity

$e:$ Electrodynamics

$\hbar:$ The quantum world

$G:$ Theory of gravity

Quantum chromodynamics and other theories of interactions also are classified with one (coupling) constant.

But pure Newtonian mechanics without gravity has no natural constants. Why? Has this historical reasons (Newton might not have had experimental stuff for measuring these constants as he formulated fundamental axioms of mechanics)?

Comment: There *is* the unit of mass. It is never written as an explicit value, but it is there.

Answer (score 1):

You are not remembering correctly [classical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics#Description_of_the_theory)(as Dmckee notes in the comments).

> The following introduces the basic concepts of classical mechanics. For simplicity, it often models real-world objects as point particles (objects with negligible size). The motion of a point particle is characterized by a small number of parameters: its position, mass, and the forces applied to it.

Constants appear important in different systems, but are not assigned uniquely to them. Actually there are three constants from which all other constants used in all physics frameworks can be derived.

Connected to mass , time, space originally, the [CGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units) system of units has evolved into  what are called ["natural units"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#.22Natural_units.22_.28particle_physics_and_cosmology.29), for particle physics, assigned the value of 1.

ħ = c = k_B = 1

[image: natural units]

Called "natural" because the mathematics becomes simple.